# C++ - Recursive function not ending

Tags: c++, function, recursion

This c++ code is not stopping after year reaches one. It should stop at 1331 (the first time it says saved). I am new to using recursion hopefully, I am not just missing something fundamental. Thank you in advanced. I have tried multiple alterations that did not work.

```
Sample input:

- Enter inital amount to save: 1000
- Enter yearly interest rate (e.g. 0.10 for 10): .1
- Enter number of years of compounded interest: 3

Output: 

 iAmount: 1100
 Years: 3
 iAmount: 1210
 Years: 2
 iAmount: 1331
 Years: 1
 Saved up: 1331
 Saved up: 1210
 iAmount: 1210
 Years: 1
 Saved up: 1210
 Saved up: 1100

void interest(int iAmount, double rate, int years, double saved){

    saved = iAmount * (1+rate);
    iAmount = saved;

    cout << "iAmount: " << iAmount << "\n";
    cout << "Years: " << years << "\n";



    while(years>1){

        years = years - 1;
        interest(iAmount, rate, years, saved);
    }
    if(years == 1){
        cout << "Saved up: " << iAmount << "\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: no while-loop required.

Comment: It's doing just what you told it to do -- remember that each `return` is going to drop back to the previous iteration of the recursion, so you end up just after each `while` loop ends.  You might want to consider why you have a `while` loop at all...

Comment: Joe and WhozeCraig, thank you. I will look into approaching this differently. This is our first assignment with recursion. If I take the while loop out, it keeps going forever.

Comment: @Jbirdwell its a little heady to wrap your head around recursion, and a piece of paper, pencil and a trivial (read: 3-4 recurses only) sample where you draw out the call-stack and local-variable states in each activation will *really* help you. Trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with recursion, you have to remember that you should be breaking your code into two separate parts: the recursive case, and the base case.

You have the right base case: `if (years == 1)`. This is your "simplest" case where you just print out the answer.

You have the right idea with the recursive case. Always think of the recursive case as "how do I make the problem a little bit simpler?" In this case, you are saying: "I can calculate the amount earned in this year," which you do using your `saved` variable. Then you indicate that you have completed this step by making the recursive call with a "simpler" problem -- namely you have reduced the number of years that need to be calculated. Eventually, you will reach the base case.

Where you are having problems is that you are making multiple recursive calls at each step. Consider a simple example of a 3 year interest rate calculation. You should be asking:

"What is my amount saved after 3 years?"

With the idea of recursion, you say: "Well, I can't answer that, but I can tell you how much you have saved after one year. Now I can ask given this new amount, how much is saved after 2 years."

This repeats until you get down to 1 year where you can print out the amount saved.

However, what you are actually doing is at the each recursive step you say: " I can tell you how much you have saved after one year, now for each year left, how much is saved after that many years." You are effectively mixing a recursive and an iterative (using loops) strategy.

I would recommend drawing out when the method calls itself (a tree-like diagram showing each recursive call and its parameters). I hope it will help you figure out why your code isn't acting as expected.

---

As a side note, be careful about [arms-reach recursion](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Science/What-is-arms-length-recursion). This is when your base case isn't as simple as it could possibly be (think about what is simpler than calculating the interest after just one year).

Comment: This is a great explanation. It helped me look at my own code from an outside perspective! Thank you. You are a good teacher.